# Are absences empty / conceptual constructions, according to all Buddhists?

Tags: sunyata

Are absences empty / conceptual constructions, according to all Buddhists? Or is it -- perhaps -- a fact independent of language that there is no elephant in this room? Does anyone know?

> A key underlying principle of the vināśitvānumāna is that negative
> facts, such as absences, are not part of the ultimate furniture of the
> world, but are just fictional conceptual constructions, as they are
> devoid of causal powers.

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dharmakiirti/

Comment: Is this question different from https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/31223/is-this-an-ok-understanding-of-dharmakirtis-vin%C4%81%C5%9Bitv%C4%81num%C4%81na ?

Comment: yes, cos i'm asking about all buddhism, not just Dharmakirti thanks for reminding me tho @Erik

Answer (score 1):

**Are absences empty / conceptual constructions**

I thought [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/35353/254) implied that an absence is unconstructed:

> So the absence of remorse is conditioned, but not being an existing thing, not having been constructed (sankharaed)-- it was the result of not-doing, is not itself subject to ending and is a small taste of Nibbana.

**is it -- perhaps -- a fact independent of language that there is no elephant in this room?**

I don't know -- sense-contact with the room gives rise to various perceptions, but none which I would label "elephant".

**they are devoid of causal powers**

You're saying that as if that's a bad thing. :-)

Comment: too meta for me, sorry

Comment: Just the the last sentence, or all of it?

Comment: i just mean your referring to an answer in your answer ha

Comment: Almost all my answers have a reference. This reference was to an answer written by Mike Olds, who's the author/editor of http://obo.genaud.net/ -- I think that answers your questions about whether "according to all Buddhists" absences are constructions -- i.e. there's a straightforward sense in which an absence is unconstructed.

Comment: it's a nice site, but who is he? it sounds enormously heterodox

Comment: It is nice, isn't it. That's all I know of him, except what he posts on this site occasionally. If [his nickname](http://obo.genaud.net/frontmatter/006_webmasters_page.htm) is "*ol'begga ols*", perhaps he is or was a monk.

Answer (score 0):

> Ākiṃcanyāyatana आकिंचन्यायतना or Ākiñcaññāyatana आकिञ्चञ्ञायतन (Tib:
> ci yang med; Chinese: 无所有处/無所有處; Jpn: 無所有処 mu sho u sho; Burmese:
> အာကိဉ္စညာယတန; Thai: อากิญฺจญฺญายตน or อากิํจนฺยายตน; Devanagari: /)
> "Sphere of Nothingness" (literally "lacking anything"). In this sphere
> formless beings dwell contemplating upon the thought that "there is no
> thing". This is considered a form of perception, though a very subtle
> one. This was the sphere reached by Ārāḍa Kālāma (Pāli: Āḷāra Kālāma),
> the first of the Buddha's original teachers; he considered it to be
> equivalent to enlightenment. Total life span on this realm in human
> years – 60,000 Maha Kalpa.

Taken literally, it implies nothingness and absences are empty.